# Java SE/EE JDK confusion

Tags: java

I want to install Netbeans for Java EE, which I did. During installation, it said JDK missing and gave me a link from where I downloaded 'SE' JDK. I couldn't really find 'EE' JDK. I might not be making any sense, but is that the JDK I want for my EE work? Netbeans got installed alright but I just want to make sure that everything Is ok. Even though I have quite a bit understanding about the basic differences in Java SE and EE. Only JDK I could find was for SE. If there is one for EE then kindly provide the link? or just let me know if I did everything right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java EE is a fundamentally different story than SE. Whereas SE contains the Java runtime and many development tools, EE is just a library. In fact, most of the library are just *interfaces* with no implementations.

This is because the *JEE application container* is the one which will provide its implementations of those interfaces. At development time you just need the interfaces to have something to refer to and NetBeans for Java EE (hopefully) already comes with those interfaces bundled.

Comment: So, I should be ok with the 'SE' jdk and Netbeans for Java EE development?

Comment: Yes, i would say so. BTW I use just a plain Java IDE to do EE as well---in a Maven-based project, all you need is a few more dependencies (net the entire EE---just those parts which you actually use).